# What are the rarest bugs/fish for?

Tags: animal-crossing-pocket-camp

So the animal neighbors will occasionally request a red snapper, black bass, or horned dynastid, which are all uncommon, but I've never seen a request for blowfish, rainbow trout, koi, emperor butterfly, etc. Are these items used for higher level requests (perhaps above level 12, my highest) or are they simply destined to fill up a slot in my inventory/market box? (Their prices tend to turn their market box slots into a trophy case.)

Comment: I'm level 21 and haven't seen a request for anything beyond a rare yet. (1,000 reward items)

Comment: You can just sell them rather than add them to the market box, if you're strapped for cash - there's a button to the right of "List for sale" labelled "Sell", which will remove it from your inventory and give you half the minimum Market Box bell quantity.  (e.g. a Koi can be listed in the Market Box for 8000 to 40000 Bells; it can be sold directly for 4000 bells.)

Answer (score 1):

When this question was posted, there was no use for such resources other than selling for bells.  However, now there is a [fairly new request type](https://www.reddit.com/r/ACPocketCamp/comments/8curv6/new_request_available_give_any_insect_fish_fruit/) that allows you to give an animal any type of a specified category of resource (ANY fish or bug or fruit etc.).  This gives the player a chance to utilize their rare items without requiring them from new players.

If you give a villager a rare item from these requests, you will typically get better rewards e.g. 1000+ bells and more resources than usual and/or a rare resource such as [bronze treats](https://animalcrossingpocketcamp.gamepedia.com/Bronze_Treats) or possibly even a fortune cookie.